# Linux export command not working

Tags: linux, bash, export

I have created a shell script in linux which uses export commands to set paths and classpath. But paths and classpath are not getting set correctly as shown below. Below is the part of script

Input:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest

export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib

echo $CLASSPATH
```

Output

```
/lib/java/latest.
```

It should be /usr/java/latest/lib. Please can someone tell me where I'm wrong or why it is returning wrong output.

Comment: Are the two exports inside a script and the echo from the shell where you invoked the script perhaps?  Was CLASSPATH set to /lib/java/latest before the script, so the script had no effect?  If the former is true, scripts are executed in subshells, so if you did something like `bash <script>` it cannot change the environment of the calling shell, though if you were to `source <script>` you could

Comment: @Eric: yes all commands are inside .sh                                                                           script:set ff=linux
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
echo $CLASSPATH

Comment: If you first line is `set ff=linux` it won't honor the shebang line (I think).  You may be running this with a shell other than bash.  If you invoke the script as `bash <script.sh>` does it work?

Comment: @Eric: Yes it works when i invoke the script as  bash ./runEAI.sh or directly as ./runEAI.sh. It also worked after removing first 2 lines of script       :set ff=linux
#!/bin/bash
But its very strange why it is not setting the correct class path.

Comment: Next time it might help to get to the bottom of the issue quicker if you post the entire script, that way we could have seen earlier that you had something before the shebang line.

Comment: @Eric:Now script is running fine. I deleted the script and created a new one with the same content. Now script is returning correct output. Might be there was some problem with the file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to source the script where you are setting the variables

```
source your_script_name
```

Or another way of sourcing is by executing your script as follows:

```
. ./your_script_name
```

Make sure there is space in between 2 dots

Comment: I am still getting the same result                                        All commands are inside .sh script                                                                  :set ff=linux
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
echo $CLASSPATH

Comment: @ronak can you please insert complete script in your question as it is

Comment: Now script is running fine. I deleted the script and created a new one with the same content. Now script is returning correct output. Might be there was some problem with the file. Thanks for your help.